# android - inflaterException in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am running an activity which contains two fragments. The first fragment is working just fine, but the second causes an inflateException and I'm not sure why. I know that it's this second fragment because when I cut it out of the activity's XML file, the program runs without error.

I've posted below the code for the fragment, its XML file, and the logcat text. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Fragment:

```
package com.example.chris.drawingtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.example.chris.drawingtest.R;

/**
 * Created by Chris on 11/28/2014.
 */
public class ToolbarFragment extends Fragment {

    ToolSelectionListener mCallback;

    public interface ToolSelectionListener {
        public void sendNewValue(int newValue);
    }

    public void clicked(ImageButton imageButton) {
        mCallback.sendNewValue(imageButton.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Toolbar Inflation", "Inflating ToolbarFragment...");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_toolbar, container, false);
    }

    private ImageButton pencilButton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pencil);
    private ImageButton eraserButton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.eraser);

}
```

Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pencil"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/pencil"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/eraser"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/eraser"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
12-01 07:49:27.788    7171-7171/com.example.chris.drawingtest D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-01 07:49:27.828    7171-7171/com.example.chris.drawingtest W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.example.chris.drawingtest is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
12-01 07:49:27.838    7171-7171/com.example.chris.drawingtest I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
12-01 07:49:27.838    7171-7177/com.example.chris.drawingtest I/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger is active
12-01 07:49:28.038    7171-7171/com.example.chris.drawingtest I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
12-01 07:49:28.038    7171-7171/com.example.chris.drawingtest I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 07:49:28.238    7171-7171/com.example.chris.drawingtest I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 07:49:28.438    7171-7171/com.example.chris.drawingtest I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 07:49:28.649    7171-7171/com.example.chris.drawingtest I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 07:49:28.839    7171-7171/com.example.chris.drawingtest I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 07:49:29.049    7171-7171/com.example.chris.drawingtest I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 07:49:29.249    7171-7171/com.example.chris.drawingtest I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
12-01 07:49:29.449    7171-7171/com.example.chris.drawingtest I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1410)
12-01 07:49:29.580    7171-7171/com.example.chris.drawingtest D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-01 07:49:29.580    7171-7171/com.example.chris.drawingtest W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4158dba8)
12-01 07:49:29.600    7171-7171/com.example.chris.drawingtest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.chris.drawingtest, PID: 7171
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chris.drawingtest/com.example.chris.drawingtest.DrawingActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.example.chris.drawingtest.DrawingActivity.onCreate(DrawingActivity.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.chris.drawingtest.ToolbarFragment.<init>(ToolbarFragment.java:43)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:590)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4778)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.example.chris.drawingtest.DrawingActivity.onCreate(DrawingActivity.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   private ImageButton pencilButton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pencil);
    private ImageButton eraserButton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.eraser);
```

`getActivity()` returns null before `onAttach`. This is causing your crash.  You can move those line inside onCreateView, for instance, but if `pencil` and  `eraser` are not part of the Activity view's hierarchy, `pencilButton` and `eraserButton` will be null

Comment: This was the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Use context being received in onAttach() and use it in other methods. Because, invoking getActivity() everytime consumes time.